# Gatsby mongodb source plugin does not display anything in Graphiql

Tags: gatsby

I'm starting with Gatsby.js, and I'm already facing problem connecting to mongodb source.

No error message at startup and I cannot see anything regarding Mongodb in Graphiql tool (I was expecting something like `allMongodbCloudDocuments`)

I'm working on **fresh Gatsby project** :

```
gatsby new my-site https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world
```

I've installed mongodb source plugin :

```
npm install --save gatsby-source-mongodb
```

And modified config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-mongodb`,
      options: {
            connectionString: `mongodb://myuser:mypassword@mysubdomain-mongodb.services.clever-cloud.com:27017`,
            dbName: 'mydbname',
            collection: `cars`
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

What am I missing?

[image: graphiql display]

Comment: This might be a silly question. Did you stop and restart `gatsby develop`?

Comment: Yes I did ;) no error at startup by the way. What should be the available collection? allMongodbCloudDocuments or allMongodbLocalDocuments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question : I've tried connection without connection string, passing all parameters individually and it works. Don't understand why, as the connection string had the same parameters :

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-mongodb`,
      options: {
        server: { address: 'mysubdomain-mongodb.services.clever-cloud.com', port: '27017' },
        auth: { user: 'myuser', password: 'mypassword'},
        dbName: 'mydbname',
        collection: `cars`
      },
    },
  ],
}
```